# Display data from certain date, from large data set

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a set of data at work, I need to analyze and summarize based on daily values. I have 48 values for each date; one for each half hour.

I've currently set up a sumif and countif-system to calcuate the average values, but I need a solution to display data from only one date, so I can assess whether the data is complete (the supplier is known to have missing data in their sensors)

As an example, this is what my data looks like. I just have 6000 lines of it this time. They come in chunks from time to time, so I never know how big a data set i will get. last one was about 2200 lines

```
11-03-2016 11:30:00:000     13,3    51,6    7,85
11-03-2016 12:00:00:000     14,9    51,6    7,85
11-03-2016 12:30:00:000     13,9    51,6    7,86
11-03-2016 13:00:00:000     14,9    51,7    7,87
11-03-2016 13:30:00:000     14,7    52      7,87
11-03-2016 14:00:00:000     14,7    52      7,88
11-03-2016 14:30:00:000     0,1     52,1    7,89
11-03-2016 15:00:00:000     0,1     52,2    7,89
11-03-2016 15:30:00:000     14,8    52,1    7,9
11-03-2016 16:00:00:000     14,8    52      7,9
11-03-2016 16:30:00:000     13,3    52      7,91
11-03-2016 17:00:00:000     12,8    51,9    7,92
11-03-2016 17:30:00:000     7,9     52      7,92
```

the dates are formatted as "general" and I can't seem to change it to any type of date nor time-format.
Right now I have a column to the left of the dates reading

```
=INT(LEFT("Range",10))
```

To pull the date from the text-formatted cell with the date. 
Ideally I'd like a cell showing the hours as well, but couldn't quite figure that one out.

What I'd like is a VBA or other piece of code, where I have one cell where I enter what date value I want to analyze, and then run the macro, and have only those 48 data points shown in seperately.
I know it's possible to set it up as a table and filter data through there, but that is very time consuming.

If it can be done without using macros (ie with something vlookup-like) i'm open to suggestions, but I can't think of any solution myself.

Comment: You could add an AutoFilter onto the header row and select the date value you want from that, thus avoiding the need for any VBA etc?

Comment: Hi Dave. As stated in the bost "I know it's possible to set it up as a table and filter data through there, but that is very time consuming".

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula to extract time:

```
=MID(A1,12,5)
```

This will result in "hh:mm". Replace the 5 with 8 to extract seconds as well.

To reliably transform the date text into date format you can use the following formula:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),MID(A1,1,2))
```

Regarding the analysis of one date: Assume cell F1 is your date input. Create a table like the following (assuming that the Time Column is column A)

```
TIME             DATETIME
00:00:00:000     =A2&" "&$F$1
00:30:00:000     =A3&" "&$F$1
...              ...
```

If you enter the Date in F1 as text in the correct format, the DateTime column will look exactly as the one from your dataset and you can use a simple Sumif() to complete your task.

**EDIT:** You could also have a look into the newly introduced PowerQuery Addin. It's natively shipped with Excel 2013 and 2016 and you can download it for free for Excel 2010. It's a brilliant way to repeatedly extract clean values from an unstructured data set. See here: [Introduction to PowerQuery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605)

**EDIT 2:** If you're really only trying to find the gaps in your dataset try the following approach: Select a column and apply the following custom date format:

```
dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss":000"
```

Afterwards enter the value *01/01/2016  00:00:00* in the first and *01/01/2016  00:30:00* in the 2nd row. Pull down as far as you want. Do a Vlookup in the column next to it and filter the results for #N/A errors. Now you have all gaps in your data. (Maybe you'll need to transform the lookup-column into text format first)